# NSXMLParser parsing xml file encoded using Windows-1256

Tags: iphone, xml, ios, encoding, nsxmlparser

i want to parse rss file in Windows-1256" encoding but it is not being read by parser 
i done alot of parsing in UTF8 encoding but only this don't work why?

[rss file with Windows-1256](http://youm7.com/Rss.asp)

Solved 
solution is

```
NSString *myStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingWindowsArabic) ];
myStr = [myStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"encoding=\"windows-1251\"" withString:@""];        
NSData* aData = [myStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:aData];
```

Comment: What `NSError` is produced by the parser?

Comment: i put break point at didendelement delegate method it doesn't stop their at all

Comment: Look at the documentation for `NSXMLParser`. If parsing fails, `-parse` returns `NO`. Then check `-parserError` to see *why*.

Comment: NSXMLParserErrorDomain code:31 operation couldn;t be completed

Comment: Now go look up `NSXMLParserErrorDomain` and see which code corresponds to `31`.

Comment: NSXMLParserUnknownEncodingError = 31

Comment: put i am writing a news app their exist another app that uses this rss with this encoding?!!!

Comment: The answer is actually already on Stack Overflow if you search for it given the information you now have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 31](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150485/nsxmlparsererrordomain-error-31)

Comment: it now parses the file latin character are correct but the Arabic character are totally wrong 
the problem is their is no windows 1256 in encoding list in NSStirng documentation

Comment: `CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingWindowsArabic)`

Comment: Problem Sloved thank you so  much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you Mohamed for the answer I kept working on it for 10 days and we found no answers at all. This is my code:

```
-(void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL {

NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
NSData * dataXml = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
NSString *myStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataXml encoding:CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingWindowsArabic)];

myStr = [myStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"encoding=\"windows-1256\"" withString:@""];
NSData *aData = [myStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSXMLParser *rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:aData];
[dataXml release];
[rssParser setDelegate:self];
[rssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
[rssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
[rssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
[rssParser parse];
[rssParser setDelegate:nil];
[rssParser release];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try this:

```
int length = str.length >100 ? 100:str.length;
NSString*mystr= [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"encoding=\".*?\"" 
                    withString:@""
                    options:NSRegularExpressionSearch 
                    range:NSMakeRange(0, length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you implement the `parseErrorOccurred:` method in your `NSXMLParser` delegate, it will give you the exact reason for the errors.

Something like:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {
    NSLog(@"NSXMLParser ERROR: %@ - %@", , [parseError localizedDescription], [parseError localizedFailureReason]);
}
```

Comment: NSXMLParserUnknownEncodingError = 31 is the erroe

Comment: Try removing the encoding line `"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1256" ?>"` from the begining of the XML data/string before parsing.  It _might_ be able to parse the document without loss of data.

Comment: yes it now parses the file but the latin characters are correct but the arabic characters are so wrong

Comment: Yea, I figured something like that may happen.  Not sure how to get NSXMLParser to read that encoding correctly.  I'll look into a few things.