# How to parse the xml response string while parser Error 81(NSXMLParserInvalidEncodingError) in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser

I am able to call https url by NSUrl methods which I can see in console. I can see the whole response xml string in console but I am not able to parse with NSXmlParser. When I am parsing it shows data null with Error 81.

Is there any other parser methods/tuts available which handles  parser Error 81(NSXMLParserInvalidEncodingError). Thanks in advance

**Updated with Xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ZSETI>
<KZRL/>
<KDMAT/>
<VIFO>V</VIFO>
<KTT>MO</KTT>
<PWERK/>
<VERARB/>
<VAN>1234</VAN>
<VPGR/>
<EINR>ABC</EINR>
 .
 .
 .</ZSETI>
```

You can also check my previous question for the same on following link [How to parse SAP business connector link in iPhone using Obj-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178574/how-to-parse-sap-business-connector-link-in-iphone-using-obj-c/12178957#comment16437270_12178957)

Comment: I have given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983514/how-to-parse-simple-xml/11984080#11984080) the answer for parsing a xml file .Please check and modify as per your xml feed
OR
Check this [tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/parsing-an-xml-file/)

Comment: Can you show us the XML response string? Does it start with an XML declaration which specifies the encoding?

Comment: In browser it start from xml tag but when I call in my application and print in console it start from <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>

Comment: I have posted some XML response above can u check and guide. thanks

Comment: please paste your code...., if you want

Comment: @elppa: I have updated question with parser code...

Comment: Please show the output of `NSLog(@"data=%@", data)`, where `data` is the complete response of the URL connection.

Comment: @Martin R : NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[data
                                                   length]);
 is Succeeded! Received 21249 bytes of data. and NSLog(@"data=%@", data) is in bytes(8 digits format ...30303030 30303030 30303030). Response string gives me full xml file in console.

Comment: The XML declaration says `encoding="utf-16"`, but the data does not look like UTF-16 !

Comment: I have followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637666/nsxmlparser-parsing-xml-file-encoded-using-windows-1256 this link and now my encoding error is finish. Only thing is I am getting [NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument' error. Can you check my updated xml and parsing code

Comment: That is a new problem and this one has been closes, so you should start a new question for that.

Comment: Yup solved:) thanks Martin for followUp.